# React how to use <Link to...> to open a page without reloading entire page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I've been able to successfuly do this in React before, but it's not working now. Here is the codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-cherry-r77lv?file=/src/App.js:0-1279

I am using https://ibaslogic.com/routing-with-react-router/ to build a sample site for learning

The main issue is with App.js.  It has two links on the page that when clicked should NOT go to a new page, but rather just open up a section from SinglePage.js. Instead, I click the link and I'm taken to a new blank page.

I have a main page called `App.js` with the two links

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom"
import SinglePage from "./pages/SinglePage"

//stylesheet
import "./pages/TempApp.css";

import Header from "./components/header";
import {
  ChakraProvider,
  // Box,
  // Text,
  // VStack,
  // Code,
  // Grid,
  theme
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
// import { ColorModeSwitcher } from '../ColorModeSwitcher';

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <Header />
      <div className="about__content">
  
  <ul className="about__list">
    <li>
      <Link to="about-app">About App</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="about-author">About Author</Link>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <Routes>
  <Route path=":slug" element={<SinglePage />}/>
  </Routes>
</div>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This page has two links: `about app` and `about author`.
I want to be able to click a link, without rerendering the whole page, just expanding the "about app" section of `SinglePage.js`

Below is the `SinglePage.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const SinglePage = () => {
  const aboutData = [
    {
      slug: "about-app",
      title: "About the App",
      description:
        "ABOUT APP: Blah ABOUT APP: Blah ABOUT APP: Blah ABOUT APP: Blah ABOUT APP: BlahABOUT APP: Blah ABOUT APP: Blah ABOUT APP: Blah ABOUT APP: Blah ABOUT APP: Blah",
    },
    {
      slug: "about-author",
      title: "About the Author",
      description:
        "ABOUT - AUTHOR blah ABOUT - AUTHOR blah ABOUT - AUTHOR blah ABOUT - AUTHOR blah ABOUT - AUTHOR blah ABOUT - AUTHOR blah ABOUT - AUTHOR blah ABOUT - AUTHOR blah ABOUT - AUTHOR blah",
    },
  ];

  const { slug } = useParams();
  const aboutContent = aboutData.find((item) => item.slug === slug);
  const { title, description } = aboutContent;

  return (
    <div className="main__content">
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SinglePage;
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just display another component inside the current page, you need to use conditional rendering.

Example of how it works:
https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-rendering-6tg9o